# AngularJS not write parameters to PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm working on an application and have problems when writing a file with a PHP hosting angular data.

I have this variable in the controller AngularJS "$scope.variables" and I want to pass a PHP and be able to write to a file

What I miss is to write to the controller in which one http.post send parameters.

In the log of the browser console I see that they are changing the data in a JSON file but when writing the file with PHP me rewrites the JSON file by defecto.No I write with the changes I made.

In the controller I have this, what it does is send the variables to the PHP page

```
$http.post ('http: //localhost/proyectos/3.0copy/app/partials/createJson.php data', data) .then (function () {
console.log ($scope.variables);
});
```

that when I run "EXPORTING TO SASS" I should generate the json file

I do not know how to make these modified angular me pass data to PHP.

[image: CONSOLE ANGULAR JS CHROME]

and my createJson.php file this:

```
  $dir='../less/variables.json';

if(file_exists($dir)) 
{ 
if(unlink($dir)) 
print "El archivo fue borrado"; 
} 
else 
print "Este archivo no existe"; 


  $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $file = fopen($dir,'w+');

  fwrite($file, $json);
  fclose($file);
```

I have a FORM with an input that is touring but I would not send my data for angular form ...

I need help to create Json.php urlwing pass in array generated by AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$myData = json_decode($_POST['datas']);

print_r($myData);

  if(file_get_contents("php://input")){
    $json = file_get_contents("php://input");

  $file = fopen($dir,'w+');
  fwrite($file, $json);
  fclose($file);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular sends it as payload and not clear data, in PHP you should be able to access it using:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))
```

Comment: it does not work. I overwritten with the same data ... @casraf

Comment: I have this variable in the controller AngularJS "$scope.variables" and I want to pass a PHP and be able to write to a file @casraf